# HDTV Signal Reception Expectations

Tags: antenna

Channels 4 and 17 are received, in contrast to the target channels 12 and 25 which do not. Attempts to move [the antenna](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00JJ5ILJ4) from indoors to outside on the balcony did not result in reception of target channels, but seemed to improve reception of existing channels (no 'tearing').

Antenna is mounted on a balcony ~15 AGL.  Signals originate from the same location, but transmission power is unknown.

## QUESTION

- Is it unreasonable to expect the target channel reception (12 & 25) if channels 4 & 17 are received?

Kudos to Tony Stewart for suggesting the website and its screenshots:
[image]

[image: UPDATE per suggestion]
[image]

http://www.tvfool.com/?option=com_wrapper&Itemid=29&q=id%3ddfafd3f6c59f8c

Comment: http://www.tvfool.com/?option=com_wrapper&Itemid=29&q=id%3ddfaf582b3e86b5

Comment: I do not mind negative feedback, however, that being said, please do not just downvote the question: either make a constructive comment or better yet: attempt to improve the question.  Please remove  the downvote unless there is a constructive comment.  Thanks –

Comment: not me.  I contributed to your question, but I share your sentiments

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75  Tony: that comment was not intended for you.  Your comment was helpful, constructive and appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very different frequency in use between those sets of channels, the working ones are 1/3rd the frequency of the ones you are not seeing, and the friis transmission equation says that right there is a 9dB increase in path loss.

Also your little spreadsheet shows some 20 odd dB difference in strength, not fully explained by the path losses.

What aerial setup are you using? Some sort of log periodic? Difficult to see much else that would cover that bandwidth well.

Personally I would be thinking of stacking a pair of yagis (One for each band of interest, and spaced at least a meter or so apart) and combining them with a suitable combiner, the combiners losses should be easily made up by the antenna gain, and using something tuned to the bands of interest will also help.

You will certainly want the aerials outside and as high as possible, roofs are good, if you can get the things well clear of surrounding metalwork.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comments.  Is this what you are thinking? https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01GEZQP12   Need to mount something in the attic due to HOA considerations

Comment: All your targets are along much the same bearing, so why bother with a rotator? Better to spend the cash on two narrowband aerials and a suitable diplexer. http://www.aerialsandtv.com/aerials.html#SignalStrength is a UK focused site which actually has mostly good information, I don't know of a US equivalent, mostly because I don't know the US practise well enough.

Comment: Any amazon.com examples and additional readings for narrowband-aerials + diplexers are appreciated.   Thanks for the very interesting link.